# Read a certain field of a bag using a parameter

Tags: apache-pig

I'm working my way through *Programming Pig* by Alan Gates and I get an error in the script introducing the power of macros: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html#macros

```
--macro.pig
-- Given daily input and a particular year, analyze how
-- stock prices changed on days dividends were paid out.
define dividend_analysis (daily, year, daily_symbol, daily_open, daily_close)
returns analyzed {
divs          = load 'NYSE_dividends' as (exchange:chararray,
                    symbol:chararray, date:chararray, dividends:float);
divsthisyear  = filter divs by date matches '$year-.*';
dailythisyear = filter $daily by date matches '$year-.*';
jnd           = join divsthisyear by symbol, dailythisyear by $daily_symbol;
$analyzed     = foreach jnd generate dailythisyear::$daily_symbol,
                    $daily_close - $daily_open;
};

daily   = load 'NYSE_daily' as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray,
        date:chararray, open:float, high:float, low:float, close:float,
        volume:int, adj_close:float);
results = dividend_analysis(daily, '2009', 'symbol', 'open', 'close');
```

The error is the unexpected `$` sign after the double colon in `dailythisyear::$daily_symbol`.

How would you solve this without replacing the line by:

```
$analyzed = foreach jnd generate divsthisyear::symbol, $daily_close - $daily_open;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter substitution cannot be used inside of macros. Parameters should be explicitly passed to macros and parameter substitution used only at the top level.

You can use the -dryrun command line argument to see how the macros are expanded in-line.

So anyways you cannot go for parameter usage in Macro this way.

Comment: Is there any source to support your answer? Because this example comes from the book _Programming Pig_ and is the example of parameter substitution within a macro, so it sounds strange that it is by definition not working. Is is a version-dependent situation? Or even the newest Pig version is not allowing this?

Comment: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#define-macros (Source of answer) For version dependencies you will have to see to it. I am not really sure.